# Why does my right Achilles hurt when I use my Sidi S Pros

Tags: shoes

My right Achilles has been hurting when I ride with my $300 Sidi S Pros, which I bought a few months ago. I don't want to waste my money by not wearing them when I ride. How can I fix my pain in my right Achilles ?????? 
Please help if you can.
Thanks

Comment: Have you seen a podiatrist or other specialist? Since everybody is unique, it'd be important to determine whether it is the shoes, your riding style, or your setup.

Comment: I'd suggest you check you seat height and the angle of the cleats.

Comment: A $300 shoe that doesn't work is not worth it. I'd recommend a Physical Therapist that knows bicycling over a podiatrist but that is in part to knowing some really good PTs and not being that impressed with the docs. Regardless, if you can't get the shoes to work, and they are the source of the pain, sell them or give them away...if you keep them you will continue to wear them.

Answer (score 5):

I've had some bad pain in my Achilles before. For me, it was a problem when I did a long ride with my seat too high and using SPD shoes and pedals. Because of the seat height, I was bending and flexing my ankles to push the pedals slightly at the bottom of each pedal stroke, this is called ankling. If you find yourself doing this, creep your seat down slightly and watch your pedaling form to see if that removes the need to apply force with your ankles during the pedal stroke.

Comment: Thanks for answering with good info. I really apreciate it